# Merge two pdfs with Ilovepdf and dompdf

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I have a code to convert an html text into pdf and another to merge this pdf with a pdf that the user uploads, but I can't merge the two together, it downloads the converted pdf and not the merged one.

When I put just to merge with two files that the user uploads it works.

My code:

```
        $dompdf = new Dompdf();
        $dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

        // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
        $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
        // Render the HTML as PDF
        $dompdf->render();
        // Output the generated PDF to Browser
        $arquivo =  $dompdf->stream();

        $ilovepdf = new Ilovepdf('iLovePdfKey', 'iLovePdfKey');
        // Create a new task
        $myTaskMerge = $ilovepdf->newTask('merge');
        // Add files to task for upload
        $arquivo = $this->convertHello();
        $file1 = $myTaskMerge->addFile('path to the file that the user upload');
        $file2 = $myTaskMerge->addFile($arquivo);
        // Execute the task
        $myTaskMerge->execute();
        // Download the package files
        $myTaskMerge->download();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$dompdf->stream()` sends the rendered PDF to the browser. As such you can't access the generated PDF that way. You have to capture the output and save to a file.

Based on your sample code, something like this:

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');
$dompdf->render();
$arquivo = $dompdf->output();
$tmp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "pdf")
file_put_contents($tmp, $arquivo);

$ilovepdf = new Ilovepdf('iLovePdfKey', 'iLovePdfKey');
$myTaskMerge = $ilovepdf->newTask('merge');
$file1 = $myTaskMerge->addFile('path to the file that the user upload');
$file2 = $myTaskMerge->addFile($tmp);
$myTaskMerge->execute();
unset($tmp);
$myTaskMerge->download();
```